# Swiftui - Metal Rendering on Apple Watch

Tags: swiftui, metal, watchos

Is it possible to render a metal shader on the Apple Watch? I can't anything about doing this but I've seen a [few examples of people doing it](https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/1047188165369495552?lang=en) but no guides. I know [MetalKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/) isn't available but are there any other ways I can render a metal shader on the Apple Watch? (I'm trying to replicate [this](https://github.com/KrisYu/Water) on the watch). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

MetalKit might not be available, but SceneKit is (that's what STS is using in this demo I think). You should be able to implement the effect you linked using a `SCNTechnique` with a custom `metalFragmentShader`.

Comment: I will give it a shot, thank you! Can you provide any material to do this? a guide or basic example?

Comment: I should note that I have the Metal Shader file that is used in this demo here: https://github.com/KrisYu/Water which Is what I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: @user Interesting. I don't think Metal is available on watchOS. Would be interesting to see if the `SCNTechnique` works with a custom Metal shader

Comment: @Leftasanexercise That's what I'm hoping to find out. I wish there was some guides doing this.